# Unable to run Visual Studio Express on Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, virtual-machine, portable-executable

I have a problem when i run Microsoft Visual Studio express 2008 Portable.

A message appears:

> (The application was unable to load a required virtual machine component, please contact the publisher of this application for more information)

Before updating to Windows 7, VS Express 2008 ran perfectly, but now I can't run it.

Comment: Why using VS Portable? I recommend you to use the install version. And try VS2012 or VS2013.

Comment: VS2012 and VS2013 have much more features.

Answer (score 0):

because it's not allowed for me to instal any application at work  so i need this version portable to create & update some application Desktop VB.><

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you're looking for but in this case I would suggest obtaining permission from your employer to install an application you need to complete your job.

There is most likely a reason for them blocking you from installing software, but a bit of asking goes a long way.

On a whim though, where are you launching the VS2008 from? If it's from the Program Files folder, try moving the application to your desktop or another folder.